# Sharing printer from CUPS to CUPS, getting state stopped 'Filter failed'

Tags: ubuntu, linux-networking, network-printer, cups

I'm trying to share a Epson TM-T20II connected to my computer (the server) via USB. It's working correctly at my computer using the drivers "EPSON TM BA Thermal".

Now in the other computer (the client) I add the shared printer using the following address: `ipp://<my_ip>/printers/EPSON_TM-T20II` and selecting the same drivers ("EPSON TM BA Thermal", installed from same files in both computers). When I try to print a test page from the client, the job arrives to the server, but it has state: stopped "Filter failed".

I have spent hours trying to solve this issue with no luck. I was finally able to make it work by adding the printer to the client through CLI instead, using the following command:

```
lpadmin -p printer_name -E -v ipp://<my_ip>/printers/EPSON_TM-T20II -m everywhere
```

So it seems to be a issue with the drivers but have no idea how to solve. I would really preffer to add the printers from the CUPS web UI instead of depending on the CLI.

Comment: Which Linux distro are you using? Which version of CUPS is installed there? (Server and client)

Answer (score 1):

***First,*** the `-m everywhere` is treating the "printer" as one which is supporting *['IPP Everywhere'](https://www.pwg.org/ipp/everywhere.html)*.

Now that "printer" is a print queue controlled by CUPS and installed on host `<my_ip>`. Since newer versions of CUPS expose all their own (shared) print queues as IPP-Everyhwere-capable on their LAN, the `-m everywhere` will work.

What is the idea of IPP Everywhere, and how does it work? The base idea of IPP Everywhere is that print clients shouldn't need to "install" any model specific driver which the administrator would have to dig up in the internet. The idea is that a print client queries the print target for its capabilities, the print target answers the query, and the client uses this information to auto-generate a PPD (*PostScript Printer Description*) appropriate for that print target. The response of the printer will most likely include that it supports PDF as a print job format... This is what `-m everywhere` accomplishes...

***Second,*** if it works from the command line, it should also work through the web interface. You'd have to select IPP or IPPS as the backend, and choose the "everywhere" printer driver.

Comment: "-m everywhere" --> helped me to solve my command line installation, i too was getting stopped "Filter failed" for the canon printer